# jQuery Tools overlay apple effect draggable with background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-tools

I have a jQuery Tools overlay with apple effect. I want to make the overlay draggable I tried using jQuery `$( ".overlay" ).draggable({ handle: "h3" });` this worked but the background image did not drag with it. How do I get the whole thing to drag?
Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZqNgy/
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because the image for the overlay is rendering outside of the div that you are setting to 'draggable'. For this to work the `<img>` element would need to be nested within the div that you are setting to draggable. If you inspect the markup you can quickly see that this is not the case.

Comment: thanks for the insight but I still can't get it to work. You would think `appendTo` would work and it kind of did but killed the effect. I tried `$("img[src='http://jquerytools.org/media/img/overlay/white.png']").appendTo('.overlay');` I'm new to jQuery and javascript and would really appreciate some help. Thanks.